# Cannot access collection from client side in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a Meteor app where I declared a collection in

```
imports/api/Dictionary.jsx
```

in that file:

```
export const dict = new Mongo.Collection('Dictionary');
```

then export it  and try to fetch data in client folder:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {dict} from "../imports/api/Dictionary.jsx";

Meteor.startup(() => {

console.log(dict.find().fetch());

});
```

But nothing showed in the console. I have tried import and fetch in server and side and everything works fine. I also installed autopublish package.

Comment: Have you tried publishing?

Comment: Do I need to use publishing when I have installed autopublish package?

Comment: Have you imported `imports/api/Dictionary.jsx`on the client side? Btw, why do you suffix your Mongo Collection file with "jsx"? It is a standard JavaScript file not a React file.

Comment: sorry, It is my bad habit when wrote a lot of front-end contents. The problem here is that I have install autopublish and somehow it just works on the server side, I have also tried to use mongol, and it shows the correct query but I am not sure whether it uses server-side or client-side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscription takes a little bit of time to receive the documents from the server. Try again after a few seconds.

Once you setup your own publication, you can use the ready callback to execute your operation once the subscription has received a full snapshot of the publication.

Comment: @GhokanKaradag Think about what autopublish does. Without any pub/sub, there is no client collection data.

Comment: Whoever downvoted you is wrong. Using the subscription `onReady` callbacks or an `autorun` is the right answer even with `autopublish` installed. Actually specifying when the data has arrived is way better than `setTimeout` and a prayer

Answer (score 1):

Even with autopublish the collection won't be *immediately* available on startup on the client. Depending on the size of the collection it might take awhile. When you use explicit pub-sub normally you can wait until the subscription is *ready* before trying to access it.

With autopublish you can try:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(dict.find().fetch());
    },
    1000);
  );
});
```

although you might have to use a bigger number than 1000 if your collection is large.

The real answer is:

1. Create a publication on the server
2. Subscribe to it on the client
3. Wait for the subscription to be `ready()`
4. Do your thing

Comment: Can I make the meteor wait until complete subscribe collection at startup time(not just specific time)?

Comment: Only if you create a named subscription, you can't do it with autopublish.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, instead of importing and exporting is the following

In a file that isnt in a client or server folder

```
this.Dictionary = new Mongo.Collection(“Dictionary”)
```

In Meteor you can declare global variables